# How to relate my models in Django - movie catalog

Tags: django, model, relationship, catalog

I am trying to write a movie catalog using Django! I cannot figure out how the model relationships work. This is a brief part of the code.
How should I define multiple roles for each cast?

```
from django.db import models

class Movie(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    casts = models.ManyToManyField(Cast)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

class Cast(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'%s %s' % (self.first_name, self.last_name)
```

Comment: Create a role model and have a many to many reference to the cast model

Comment: class Contributor(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    email = models.EmailField()
    roles = models.ManyToManyField(Role)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'%s %s' % (self.first_name, self.last_name)

class Role(models.Model):
    role_title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.role_title